# Three.js - Environment map renders black

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to apply an environment map to a sphere, and followed both of the following tutorials to set up a basic scene with correct (as far as I can tell) lighting and geometry:

- http://www.aerotwist.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-three-js/
- http://www.aerotwist.com/tutorials/create-your-own-environment-maps/demo/

For some reason, however, the sphere renders as a simple flat black disk when I add the environment map. Without the envMap setting it renders the colored sphere correctly.

The full code is below, which is called from the .html file with Sphere.init() after the DOM loads:

```
Sphere = {
init: function(){
    this.WIDTH = 800;
    this.HEIGHT = 600;
    this.VIEW_ANGLE = 45;
    this.ASPECT = this.WIDTH / this.HEIGHT;
    this.NEAR = 0.1;
    this.FAR = 10000;

    var container = $('#sphere');

    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    this.VIEW_ANGLE,
    this.ASPECT,
    this.NEAR,
    this.FAR
    );

    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.scene.add(this.camera);
    this.camera.position.z = 300;
    this.renderer.setSize(this.WIDTH, this.HEIGHT);

    container.append(this.renderer.domElement);

    var urls = [
  'pos-x.png',
  'pos-x.png',
  'pos-x.png',
  'pos-x.png',
  'pos-x.png',
  'pos-x.png'
    ],

cubemap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube(urls);
    cubemap.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

    var reflectionMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: 0x0000ff,
  envMap: cubemap
});

    var radius = 50, segments = 16, rings = 16;
    var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, segments, rings);
    var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, reflectionMaterial);
    this.scene.add(sphere);

    var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF);
    pointLight.position.x = 10;
    pointLight.position.y = 50;
    pointLight.position.z = 130;
    this.scene.add(pointLight);

    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only issue is that your declaring both: urls and cubemap at the same time. Therefore cubemap has no idea what urls is yet. Seperate the var declarations, and I bet you get it working.

```
var urls = [
    'pos-x.png',
    'pos-x.png',
    'pos-x.png',
    'pos-x.png',
    'pos-x.png',
    'pos-x.png'
];

var cubemap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube(urls);
```